# Convert PDF documents (.pdf) to EXCEL document (.XLXS) using PHP

Tags: php, html, web

I have a set of pdf documents and I need to convert the files to excel. When I tried to convert those I could not convert it was stating failed. So I have tried to convert to HTML tag all the data are converting but it was changing the whole document into P tags. I have attached the sample response of HTML tags. Please suggest me some ides for converting pdf to excel in php.

I have used [this](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9423-PHP-Convert-PDF-to-HTML-using-Poppler.html) library

```
<p class="ft00" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 11px; font-family: Times; color: #000000; position: absolute; top: 863px; left: 683px; white-space: nowrap;"><b>10</b></p>
<p class="ft01" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 9px; font-family: Times; color: #000000; -moz-transform: matrix(         0,         -1,  0.9999875,          0, 0, 0); -webkit-transform: matrix(         0,         -1,  0.9999875,          0, 0, 0); -o-transform: matrix(         0,         -1,  0.9999875,          0, 0, 0); -ms-transform: matrix(         0,         -1,  0.9999875,          0, 0, 0); -moz-transform-origin: left 75%; -webkit-transform-origin: left 75%; -o-transform-origin: left 75%; -ms-transform-origin: left 75%; position: absolute; top: 207px; left: 63px; white-space: nowrap;"><b>THE</b></p>

Library: PdfToHtml


$pdf = new \TonchikTm\PdfToHtml\Pdf($pdf_file , [
    'pdftohtml_path' => $bindir,
    'pdfinfo_path' => $binexe,
    'outputDir' => getcwd().'/excelfile/'.uniqid() // output dir 
]);

$newpage = '';
foreach ($pdf->getHtml()->getAllPages() as $page) {
    $newpage .= $page . '<br/>';
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never had a use case to convert PDF to Excel, but what other libraries did you try?

PDFTables looks promising:

https://pdftables.com/pdf-to-excel-api#php

https://github.com/pdftables/php-pdftables-api

If it needs to be done with the PDF to HTML library you're using, I don't know of an easy/clean way to do this.

Based on the Question, each page returns a string containing all the paragraph elements?

If returns an array of elements, you should be able to loop over each paragraph and use strip_tags() to get the individual values.

If it's a string, look into using [Simple HTML Dom](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/) to parse the HTML elements from string format so that you can work with the HTML more easily.

```
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');
```

Comment: I have checked PDF table, but it was too pricy  they were asking me more than 40$ for converting 1000 pages

Comment: Then I have used Tabula . That also converting not happening

Comment: It might be hard to find a quality tool for this without paying for it since PDF conversion is not always straight forward. Have you tried parsing the HTML with Simple HTML Dom? What happens with Tabula? Do you get errors or does it not work at all? It might make sense to create a new question with what you've tried and what current error you're running into.